# Check the symmetry of a grid/truth table

Tags: c++, c, truthtable

```
t t f f f f t t
t t f f f f t t
f f t t t t f f
f f t t t t f f
t t f f f f t t
t t f f f f t t
f f t t t t f f
f f t t t t f f
```

Is it possible to determine the symmetry of the above 8x8 using 8-input truth tables e.g. OR, AND, XOR, etc?

Comment: You mean aside from repeatedly picking pairs and doing NOT XOR?

Comment: You mean pick the pairs?

Comment: Yes. And how does the NOT XOR help determine the symmetry? Could you give an example?

Comment: I guess I'll post an answer with more details then.

Comment: Kevin, what exactly do you mean by “symmetry”? Which of the 64 values would you put into an “8-input truth table,” by which I believe you probably mean some Boolean function, given your examples?

Comment: By symmetry, I mean horizontal/vertical symmetry.

Suppose I have all 64 possible combinations of t/f in the table. And the result of the table is AND, OR, XOR, etc. For e.g. AND table for 2-input with 8 combinations  
f f f  
f t f  
t f f  
f f f

Comment: Oh, then you need to adapt my answer from below. I thought you meant symmetry around the main diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean symmetry the same way I do and that you have the input in something like a `bool[][]` or an `std::vector<std::vector<bool> >` (or `char` instead of `bool`, it doesn't really matter as long as `==` works), you'd simply iterate over one half of the matrix and compare with the other half, something like this:

```
bool symmetric = true;
for (unsigned int i = 1; symmetric && i <= n; ++i) {
  for (unsigned int j = i+1; symmetric && j <= n; ++j) {
    symmetric = (M[i][j] == M[j][i]);
  }
}
```

Note that you don't need to check the diagonal, which is why `i` starts at 1 and `j` at `i+1` in the code above.

(I tend to write more parentheses and braces than some people like. I just happen to prefer code written that way.)

---

EDIT:

You can have a 64-input table that tells you which inputs are symmetric, sure. With a bit of compression, you could store that table in 2097152 TB of memory. I guess the looping code can run pretty often before you are finished loading this table for lookup. Instead, you could of course enter the six non-trivial lines parallel to the antidiagonal into corresponding truth tables, since if they are symmetric, the whole matrix is. Those tables (for 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8 inputs) would easily fit into a few hundred bytes.

But it seems your interpretation of symmetry is different from mine, anyway. If you are interested in whether each row and/or each column is symmetric, then, obviously, you can use truth tables for that. Stroing them takes 256 bits, so if you are really short on space, you could squeeze them into 8 bits, but lookup is probably faster when you spend 256 bytes on it.

Comment: What about the "using 8-input truth tables e.g OR, AND, XOR, etc?" part ?

Comment: Right, there was that part, where quite frankly, I have no idea what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I need to use the truth tables instead of comparisons.

Comment: Well, it was a question as I did not know what kind of tables would be best suitable.

But suppose I could create an 8-input truth tables for AND, OR, XOR,etc operations would it be possible to determine the symmetry?

Comment: As asked above: Which of the 64 values would you put into that 8-input table?

Comment: Suppose I have all 64 possible combinations of t/f in the table. And the result of the table is AND, OR, XOR, etc.  

For e.g. AND table for 2-input with 8 combinations
f f        f  

f t        f  

t f        f  

f f        f

Answer (score 0):

So, what I said in the comment is to repeatedly check certain pairs and do "NOT XOR" on them.

The idea with the pairs is that if a row is symmetric, there are certain pairs that have to be equal. Noting that we zero index arrays, we have that within each row, the pairs will have indices 0 and 7, 1 and 6, 2 and 5, and 3 and 4. For the row to be symmetric, all 4 of those have to be matching pairs. In all, for the table to be symmetric, there are 32 pairs to check (the 4 pairs in each row, over 8 rows).

The trick with NOT XOR is that since XOR returns true iff the two are different, the negation of that statement returns true iff the two are the same.

So, if you wanted to do this entire check using only boolean operations, you'd take each of those pairs, (call it (a,b) for now) and do (NOT(a XOR b)) (`!(a^b)` in code), then AND the results of all 32 of those checks.

Granted, if I were actually doing this in code, I'd much rather just do a regular check for equality.

Comment: NOT XOR feels kind of weird. Equality works just fine, doesn't it?

Comment: It does, I just brought up the NOT XOR stuff in case the OP needs to only use boolean operations for some odd reason. I'd use equality for any sane use case.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Will try this out.
Yes, I would be using an equality check as well but there is a requirement to do it using truth tables.

Comment: Well, `!(a^b)` is not exactly a truth table, is it?

Comment: You can make a truth table for it though.